# iPhone -- [UITextField sizeToFit] does not always account for cursor

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

When I call sizeToFit on a UITextfield that is being edited, the size reacts in an inconsistent way to the cursor.  Sometimes it accounts for it; sometimes it doesn't.  If it doesn't, part of the first letter is clipped.

Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem (it's fixed in iOS 5). My solution was to add a 4-point padding to the width:

```
[textField_ sizeToFit];
textField_.frame = CGRectMake(textField_.frame.origin.x,
                              textField_.frame.origin.y, 
                              CGRectGetWidth(textField_.frame) + 4,
                              CGRectGetHeight(textField_.frame));
```

A bit tedious but got the job done for me.